# How do I retrieve the "stats" property from "srtserversink" and print the ouput while running the Gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I want to print stats from the srtserversink while the Gstreamer pipeline is running.
The srtserversink has a property called "stats", but I have not found a way to extract this data.
Any suggestions would be welcome!

Below is the definition of the stats property and my code:

---

stats               : Array of GstStructures containing SRT statistics
flags: readable
GstValueArray of GValues of type "GstStructure"

---

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // Initialize GStreamer
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    //Creating GStreamer elements
    GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("my-pipeline");
    GstElement *src = gst_element_factory_make("nvarguscamerasrc", "src");
    GstElement *encoder = gst_element_factory_make("omxh264enc", "encoder");
    GstElement *muxer = gst_element_factory_make("mpegtsmux", "muxer");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make("srtserversink", "sink");

    //Check if all elements are successfully created
    if (!pipeline || !src || !encoder || !muxer || !sink) 
    {
        g_printerr("Failed to create elements. Exiting.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Setting parameters for elements
    g_object_set(src, "sensor-id", 0, nullptr);
    g_object_set(src, "sensor-mode", 0, nullptr);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(encoder), "insert_sps_pps", true, nullptr);
    g_object_set(encoder, "bitrate", 25000, nullptr);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "uri", "srt://:7008", "latency", 100, nullptr);

    //Add elements to the pipeline
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), src, encoder, muxer, sink, nullptr);

    //Check if all elements are successfully added to the pipeline
    if (!gst_element_link_many(src, encoder, muxer, sink, nullptr)) 
    {
        g_printerr("Failed to link elements. Exiting.\n");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }
  
    //Start the pipeline
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    
    //Wait until error or EOS
    GstBus *bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    GstMessage *msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));
    
    //Stop the pipeline
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    //Clean up GStreamer
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to make a separate function that takes the "sink" as a parameter, but I was unsuccessful in retrieving data from the stats property.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should use the [srtsink element](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/srt/srtsink.html?gi-language=c).
`srtsink` has a `stats` property where you can read some stats, for example 'bytes-sent-total' or 'packets-sent' you read the stats like this:

```
GstStructure* stats = nullptr;
g_object_get(sink, "stats", &stats, nullptr);
if (stats) {
     guint64 bytes_sent = 0;
     gint64 packets_sent = 0;
     gst_structure_get(stats, "bytes-sent-total", G_TYPE_UINT64, &bytes_sent, "packets-sent", G_TYPE_INT64, &packets_sent, nullptr);
     gst_structure_free(stats);
}
```